# Does completeness of the theory of a bijection without finite orbits depend on choice?

Tags: lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Consider the following sentences in a first-order language with one unary function symbol $f$:

$\forall x \exists y (fy=x)$

$\forall y\forall z(fy=fz\to y=z))$

$\forall x (\underbrace{f\dotsb f}_{n\mbox{ times}}x\neq x)$

so that any model of them is just a set equipped with a bijection with no finite orbits.  This is the simplest list of axioms I could think of which has countably many non-isomorphic countable models and is uncountably categorial *if* you believe in Zorn's lemma,  and this theory is therefore complete. Surely completeness of this theory doesn't depend on the axiom of choice. Does it?

Comment: George, welcome to MathOverflow. It is a very nice question. I wanted to mention that in addition to accepting Emil's great answer, it is also possible for you to upvote it (as I have), and this would be normal if indeed you find it worthwhile.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several ways how to prove the completeness of this theory (let me call it $S$) without choice:

1. Prove in a purely syntactic way (by induction on the complexity of a formula) that $S$ has quantifier elimination.
2. Observe that $S$ has only one countable recursively saturated model.

   For an elementary version of this argument: expand $S$ to a theory $S'$ with countably many constants $\{c_n:n\in\omega\}$, and axioms that $c_n$ is not reachable from $c_m$ in finitely many steps for $n\ne m$. Using the compactness theorem, you easily show that if $\phi$ is consistent with $S$, it is consistent with $S'$, hence it holds in a countable model of $S'$ (this needs no choice as the language is countable). But reducts of countable models of $S'$ in the original language are all isomorphic (they consist of countably many copies of $(\mathbb Z,s)$).
3. Show that any two models of $S$ are elementarily equivalent by an Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé argument. Or, apply a ready-made EF argument: Gaifman's locality theorem.
4. The completeness of $S$ is an arithmetical ($\Pi_2$) statement. Thus, you can just prove the result in ZFC, and use the conservativity of ZFC over ZF for arithmetical sentences.

Comment: Expanding on (3) (which applies to all theories) for the OP: the key point here is the definition and basic analysis of Godel's constructible universe $L$. For every finite $T\subset \mathsf{ZFC}$ we have a $\mathsf{ZF}$-proof that $T$ holds in $L$, and moreover we have a separate $\mathsf{ZF}$-proof that every arithmetical sentence true in $L$ is actually true; now given a $\mathsf{ZF}$-proof that your theory is complete, apply the above with $T$ the axioms used. None of this is quite trivial but once it's all put together we have a powerful black-boxable result for de-choiceifying arguments.

Comment: I was hoping someone would come along and explain that part a bit. Where can I learn about this? It seems like black magic to me.

Comment: @GeorgeHayduke This is basically the Shoenfield absoluteness theorem.

Comment: Preservation of the truth of arithmetic sentences to transitive models of ZF such as $L$ follows immediately from the absoluteness of $\omega$. There is no need for anything as sophisticated as Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem.